# Como alimentar um array usando dados de outro array em php?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Não aceita o foreach?

```
{        $ssparray = array(
            //Array numérico sendo a segunda dimensão.
            'mensagem' => array(
              'mensagem'                => 'OK - preventiva realizada',
              'usuario_api'             => 'userapi', 
              'relatorio_fotografico'   => 'rf', 
              'data_de_execucao_inicio' => $inicio,
              'data_de_execucao'        => $fim,
              'preventiva_id'           => $ordemservico->codigocliente,
            ),
            /*
            //Array Associativo sendo a segunda dimensão.
            foreach ($fotos as $foto) {
                'checklist' => array(
                    'id[i]'    => $foto->checklistitens_id,
                    'nome'  => $foto->checklistitens->descricao,
                    'valor' => $foto->situacao,
                )
            }
            */
}
```

Comment: Esse trecho do seu código está incompleto e não dá nem para fazer uma analise do problema. Você está criando um array dentro de outro array já tendo a sua construção com um foreach. E eu não tenho certeza, mas acredito que isso não funcione.

Comment: Sim, este é o problema. Não estou sabendo como fazer mesmo! Um foreach dentro de um array não funciona. Coloquei ali para dar uma ideia do que preciso mas vou reformular. Obrigado.

Comment: Eu vou fazer uma estrutura um código da forma correta de se fazer, mas não sei se vai te atender, por que ainda falta trechos do seu código.

Comment: Dentro deste sspaarray pode ter quantos checklists?

Comment: Dentro do checklist hoje tem 28 itens mas eu pego de uma tabela que pode aumentar ou diminuir.
Obrigado. Clareou a forma como fez e sim, estou estudando agora mesmo como fazer.

Comment: Agora entendi [$i] que colocou, vou fazer a adaptação.

Comment: Se colocar o retorno do Eloquent posso ajudar com o código, com esse código só vejo PHP puro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na nova foma de se fazer um array utilizamos $var = [] ao invés de $var = array()
Sugiro que estude sobre o assunto no site do [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php)

Como a sua pergunta está um pouco vaga, fiz apenas correções de sintaxe e acredito que vá ajudar.

```
//Array Associativo sendo a segunda dimensão.
$checklist = [];
foreach ($fotos as $foto)
{
    $checklist['id']    = $foto->checklistitens_id;
    $checklist['nome']  = $foto->checklistitens->descrica;
    $checklist['valor'] = $foto->situacao;
}

$ssparray = [
//Array numérico sendo a segunda dimensão.
'mensagem' => [
'mensagem'                => 'OK - preventiva realizada',
'usuario_api'             => 'userapi',
'relatorio_fotografico'   => 'rf',
'data_de_execucao_inicio' => $inicio,
'data_de_execucao'        => $fim,
'preventiva_id'           => $ordemservico->codigocliente,
],
'checklist' => $checklist
];
```

Comment: O resultado foi: No caso o "checklist" => array:3 pode ter 28 itens
{
array:2 [▼
  "mensagem" => array:6 [▼
    "mensagem" => "OK - preventiva realizada"
    "usuario_api" => "userapi"
    "relatorio_fotografico" => "rf"
    "data_de_execucao_inicio" => "2019-10-31 10:51:55"
    "data_de_execucao" => "2019-10-31 16:46:32"
    "preventiva_id" => null
  ]
  "checklist" => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 437
    "nome" => "OUTROS AMBIENTES (ESPECIFICAR)"
    "valor" => "C"
  ]
]
}

Comment: Deu certo, era isso que queria?

Comment: Eu uso o eloquent para relacionar e pegar como um array os dados da ordem de serviço, checklist e checklistitens como:
{
        $fotos = Foto::with('checklistitens', 'ordemservico')
            ->orderBy('checklistitens_id', 'asc')
            ->where('ordemservico_id', "$ordemservico")
            ->get();
}

Comment: Deixa eu ver se eu entendi. Você pega os valores da tabela fotos e depois usa esse resultado pra trazer valores de outra tabela(checklistitens), é isso? E está trazendo o resultado que você quer?

Comment: Resultado (laravel-eloquent) da table fotos relacionada com checklistitens. Tem 29 checklistitens e estes que devem estar no array checklist que você fez. Tive que cortar no código por causa do tamanho.
{
Collection {#668 ▼
  #items: array:30 [▼
    0 => Foto {#634 ▼
    #observables: []
      #relations: array:2 [▼
        "checklistitens" => Checklistitens {#669 …26}
        "ordemservico" => Ordemservico {#632 …26}
      ]
    }
    1 => Foto {#635 ▶}
    1 => Foto {#635 ▶}
    2 => Foto {#636 ▶}
    3 => Foto {#637 ▶}

Comment: Sim, traz o resultado que preciso. Preciso fazer o loop do array checklist para montar com o total de checklistitens (São 29).

Comment: Bom se a minha resposta ajudou, marque como respondida

Comment: Deu certo sim. Obrigado.
Agora vou fazer uns ajustes e estudar mais sobre a questão do collect do eloquent.

Answer (score 1):

Marcos, boa tarde como esta usando Eloquent, existe varias formas de mapear um Array no Laravel e conseguir o resultado que você quer, você pode usar a função map da collecet(),
pois o seu retorno retornou uma collect, voce pode criar uma collect nova e usar o metodo push, iterando sobre seu array atual ou como falado anteriormente com o map.